# How to Install Flex in Ubuntu 12.04.03 LTS?

Tags: software-installation

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.03 LTS.
i want to install flex. but i m not able to install flex.
can you tell me how to install flex ?
show me step by step process to install flex ....

Answer (score 0):

Below commands will install `flex` package on your Ubuntu pc.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flex
```

Comment: i have used these commands still few errors are there...

Comment: Post the output of `sudo apt-get install flex` command.

Comment: output of sudo apt-get install flex command.

compaq@compaq-Compaq-510:~$ sudo apt-get install flex
[sudo] password for compaq :
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependancy tree
Reading state information... Done
Package flex is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'flex' has no installation candidate

Comment: post the output of `apt-cache policy flex`

Comment: And were there any errors with sudo apt-get update?

Comment: @ Avinash :- 
output of apt-cache policy flex


flex:
 
Installed: (none)
 
Candidate: (none)
 
Version table: